# Geolocation method to see if user in specific area

Tags: javascript, geolocation, cordova

i'm developing an application for a Restaurant in Portugal called Olivier.
Currently I'm studying geolocation api of phonegap, and I haven't find a way to solve my problem that is to check if the user position is inside the restaurant.

To be more specific I want my application to show a menu if the user is inside the restaurant area (trough geolocation) and to show a different menu if he's outside the restaurant area.

I would be glad if you answer a link to a guide or just write the method i'll need to use, so I can proceed with the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you're using google maps api:

You can use this: [containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon) : Computes whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly)

to check if current geolocation is inside a given polygon (the restaurant area)

### If you are not:

If your not using google maps API, im afraid u can only do an approximation by calculating the radius of the restaurant, and check if the distance between cur position and restaurant center is < than radius

Boa sorte com a aplicação :)

Comment: obrigado, mas é trabalho para o estágio, nem vou ganhar nada com isto :S