# How can I determine if a postal code is inside a defined area?

Tags: geolocation

I’m building an ordering/delivery website for a restaurant with a PHP backend.

I’d like to determine if the delivery postal code (Canada) is within a predetermined delivery zone. The zone is oddly shaped around specific streets and neighborhood, so radius is not an option.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I assume Google Maps could help with that but I haven’t found any clear path yet.

Comment: Finally found a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980424/geolocation-method-to-see-if-user-in-specific-area

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
if ($zip > 5600 && $zip < 6000) {
  //do stuff
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Canadian postal codes are organised in some kind of 2d layout, not along a line.

Answer (score 0):

You have to map GIS data to your postal codes. Maybe such a mapping already exists and you "only" have to asked "Canada Post" for it (assuming a commercial project).