# How to check if the user's address is in my area or not using maps in flutter. I want to provide services to a user in a particular area

Tags: flutter, dart, location, maps, coordinates

If the user is not in my area of service I want to show a error screen
I would highly appreciate if the answer is in a code or a relevant resource. Thank you

Comment: You can check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980424/geolocation-method-to-see-if-user-in-specific-area

Comment: thank you!@HamzaAzam. can u please elaborate on implementation of this in flutter.